# What is the shortest way to divide 2 32-bit signed integers?

Tags: assembly, x86

I have two 32-bit signed integers in `EAX` and `EBX` respectively. If I do:

```
xor EDX, EDX
idiv EBX
```

Then, `EAX` is treated as unsigned 32-bit, and that's wrong. `MOVSX` doesn't seem to be able to extend sing bit from `EAX` to `EDX:EAX`. I also tried to play with `CMP` and `SBC`, but I wasn't able to find a solution.

I'd like to know the shortest possible code to do it, or at least code which avoids jumps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an instruction for that:

```
CDQ
```

It sign-extends the 32 bit value stored in EAX to a 64 bit register pair EDX:EAX. This is exactly that register-pair that is the argument for the IDIV instructions.

Your code would look like this:

```
  CDQ
  IDIV EBX
```

Here is more information about that instruction:

http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/cdq.htm

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't get converted. `idiv` is signed divison, which divides the 64 bit value of `edx:eax` by the operand of `idiv`, placing the remainder to `edx` and the quotient to `eax`. I cannot think of any faster way, than this. If you really think it gets converted somehow, try the `CDQ` instruction. It does the following:

> Sign-extends EAX into EDX, forming the quad-word EDX:EAX. Since (I)DIV uses EDX:EAX as its input, CDQ must be called after setting EAX if EDX is not manually initialized (as in 64/32 division) before (I)DIV.